# Функция задержки времени

Tags: c++, linux

Для задержки времени обычно юзаю `sleep()` из `unistd.h`, но эта функция принимает в качестве аргумента секунды, а иногда задержку нужно поставить менее 1 секунды. Какой есть аналог этой функции, который принимает значение в милисекундах?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы используете С++11, то в стандартную библиотеку добавлена кроссплатформенная функция [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) для возможности блокировать текущее выполнение потока на заданный промежуток времени.

В качестве промежутка времени передаётся класс [std::chrono::duration](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), который предназначен для задания промежутка времени в различных единицах измерения.

Например,

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(ssec));   
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(usec));  
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));    
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(sec));        
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(min));        
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours(hrs));
```

***Дополнительно***: в стандарте **С++14** имеются предопределённые [пользовательские литералы](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), которые позволяют задать интервалы времени в различных единицах измерения в более читабельном виде. 
 Например, если вы хотите установить sleep потоку на *100 миллисекунд*, то вместо того, чтобы писать так

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```

можно написать так

```
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
```

Эти куски кода эквивалентны, но второй вариант выглядит более читабельным.

Comment: И выражение "более легко-читаемым" тоже можно  заменить выражением "читабелней", что  является читабелней первого... А если без шуток, то думаю вы правы

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, если верить [этому](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431317/ЧИТАЕМЫЙ-и-ЧИТАБЕЛЬНЫЙ-в-чём-разница), правильнее употреблять читабельный. Поэтому ваше замечание верное.

Answer (score 1):

Функция usleep(). Задаёт ожидание в микросекундах (1000000 микросекунд = 1 секунда, 1000 микросекунд = 1 милисекунда). Пример:

```
#include <unistd.h>

const unsigned int microseconds = 683;

int main()
{
    // ...
    usleep(microseconds);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: во-первых, стоит помнить, что `usleep ()` — это POSIX, а во-вторых он объявлен устаревшим в пользу `nanosleep ()`