# Можно ли параметром функции Sleep() задать переменную?

Tags: c++

Есть в С++ функция `Sleep()`, которая приостанавливает программу на некоторое время. Это время указывается в параметре функции и выражается в миллисекундах. А можно ли задать параметром переменную?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду ф-цию `sleep` из `unistd.h`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814920/Функция-задержки-времени/814934#814934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, вы имеете в виду - задать параметр переменной?

Да, конечно.

```
int sleep_time = 1000;

Sleep(sleep_time);
```

Только как мелкое замечание - эта функция не входит в стандартную библиотеку С++, так что говорить о ней как "есть в С++ функция" не совсем корректно...